From excel time to a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
In Excel I have the next table:
B       C             D                         E
id   building     inauguration_date           sql_insert
-------------------------------------------------------
1   "Blue A"     "2027-03-11 01:07:00"
2   "RED  B"     "2026-05-12 01:00:00"

The sql_insert column will be used to create an sql cmd to insert the data at the B,C,D columns. I tried creating the next formula:
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO myReport (id, building, inauguration_date) VALUES ('", B2, "', '",C2,"', '", D2,"')")

However, for the inauguration_date I get values as: 46457.0465277778
Yet I need the string "2027-03-11 01:07:00" to be placed instead as that insert cmd will be used for sqllite3. What Excel function will allow me to do this conversion?

You will need TEXT() function here, probably something like this: =CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO myReport (id, building, inauguration_date) VALUES ('", B2, "', '", C2, "', '", TEXT(D2, "e-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"), "')")
